# Cannot Compile Golang programs Using the Go-Ethereum package

Tags: go-ethereum

I have been trying to follow the goethereumbook.org/en/client at the section "Setting Up the Client" for hours.

Here is my version of golang:

```
~/g/gwal (main) [2]> go version
go version go1.18.2 linux/amd64
```

I did the following steps to install go-ethereum:

```
[I] tsalim@meerkat ~/g/gwal (main) [1]> go get github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
```

And then I wrote a program to establish a connection with `Dial`. Here is the program below:

```
package main

import
(
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io")

    if err != nil   {
        
        log.Fatal(err);
    }

    fmt.Println("we have a connection")

}
```

And then I try to build the package but I always get:

```
[I] tsalim@meerkat ~/g/gwal (main)> go build -o wal.og wal.go
# github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc
../../go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc/server.go:49:11: cannot use generic type mapset.Set[T comparable] without instantiation
../../go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc/server.go:54:69: cannot infer T (/home/tsalim/go/src/github.com/deckarep/golang-set/set.go:180:13)
../../go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc/websocket.go:72:26: cannot infer T (/home/tsalim/go/src/github.com/deckarep/golang-set/set.go:180:13)
../../go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc/websocket.go:125:37: cannot use generic type mapset.Set[T comparable] without instantiation
```

What faults are there in how I install the go-ethereum package? I must be installing

something the wrong way. I am new to Golang modules after all.

I thank anyone for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

On closer inspection, the issue is caused by breaking changes to **github.com/deckarep/golang-set** v2.1.0 module dependency, works fine on previous v1.7.1.

To fix, simply download the source code for **github.com/deckarep/golang-set** v1.7.1, and copy to your GOPATH. Works until support for golang-set v2.1.0 is added to go-ethereum.